# Python path issue with dirname: command not found and conda environment python not found

Tags: macos, python, path, anaconda

I am running MacOS Catalina (10.15). It is now giving me multiple issues with bash. It gives me the following two errors. Are they related, and if so, how would I fix them?

```
(base) dhcp-10-105-176-29:cpotts-swda adamg$ conda activate swda
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
(swda) dhcp-10-105-176-29:cpotts-swda adamg$ echo $PATH
/bin:/bin:/Users/adamg/anaconda3/envs/swda/bin:/bin:/Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.7/bin
(swda) dhcp-10-105-176-29:cpotts-swda adamg$ python
-bash: python: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash can't find the commands (`dirname` and `python`) because your `$PATH` variable is not setup properly.

Add this line to the end of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
```

From [GNU bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables):

```
PATH

A colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands.
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know what I did to my system, but when I try to open `~/.bash_profile` with vim or nano, I get `-bash: nano: command not found`

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Or just run `echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Then open a new terminal to see if things work normally.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I forgot I had added this line to the end of my file last week, to try to install a library: `export PATH="/Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.7/bin"`. is that what caused all of this?

Comment: Yeah, you most likely want to append to path like this `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.7/bin"` instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Overwriting PATH is like telling bash:  "Look here for all the commands and nowhere else". Which caused bash to not be able to find pretty much anything.

Comment: Ahhhh, that totally makes sense. Thank you again!